# Cannot access ports in AWS ECS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, port, amazon-ecs

I am running an AWS ECS service which is running a single task that has multiple containers.
Tasks are run in awsvpc network mode. (EC2, not Fargate)

Container ports are mapped in the ECS task definition.

I added inbound rules in the EC2 Container instance security group (for ex: TCP 8883 -> access from anywhere). Also in the VPC network security group.

When I try to access the ports using Public IP of the instance from my remote PC, I get `connection refused`.

For ex: `nc -z <PublicIP> <port>`

When I SSH into the EC2 instance and try netstat, I can see SSH port 22 is listening, but not the container ports (ex: 8883).
Also, when I do `docker ps` inside instance, Ports column is empty.

I could not figure out what configuration I missed. Kindly help.

PS: The destination (Public IP) is reachable from the remote PC. Just not from the port.

Comment: you ssh to server and see port 22 is lisening, how about port 8883 ?

Comment: port 8883 is not listening. docker ps inside the instance shows PORTS column as empty. But in my task definition, the ports are mapped.

Comment: can you share `dockerfile` for the app ?

Comment: Which `Host` port is mapped to the `Container` port in your task definition?

Comment: FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx/certs/ /etc/nginx/certs/
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]


do I need to expose the port in dockerfile too? even if it is configured in the task definition ContainerPort

Comment: @Pacifist I am using the awsvpc network mode. So, I cannot map the host port.

Answer (score 8):

> I am running an AWS ECS service which is running a single task that
>   has multiple containers. Tasks are run in awsvpc network mode. (EC2,
>   not Fargate)

**Ec2, not Fargate**, different horse for different courses. The task that is run against **awsvpc network mode** has own elastic network interface (ENI), a primary private IP address, and an internal DNS hostname. so how you will access that container with AWS EC2 public IP?

> The task networking features provided by the awsvpc network mode give
>   Amazon ECS tasks the same networking properties as Amazon EC2
>   instances. When you use the awsvpc network mode in your task
>   definitions, every task that is launched from that task definition
>   gets its own elastic network interface (ENI), a primary private IP
>   address, and an internal DNS hostname. The task networking feature
>   simplifies container networking and gives you more control over how
>   containerized applications communicate with each other and other
>   services within your VPCs.

[task-networking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html)

So you need to place LB and then configure your service behind LB.

> when you create any target groups for these services, you must choose
>   ip as the target type, not instance. This is because tasks that use
>   the awsvpc network mode are associated with an ENI, not with an Amazon
>   EC2 instance.

So something wrong with the configuration or lack of understanding between network mode. I will recommend reading this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html).

> when I do docker ps inside instance, Ports column is empty.

So it might be the case below if the port column is empty.

> The host and awsvpc network modes offer the highest networking
>   performance for containers because they use the Amazon EC2 network
>   stack instead of the virtualized network stack provided by the bridge
>   mode. With the host and awsvpc network modes, exposed container ports
>   are mapped directly to the corresponding host port (for the host
>   network mode) or the attached elastic network interface port (for the
>   awsvpc network mode), so you cannot take advantage of dynamic host
>   port mappings.

Keep the following in mind:

> It’s available with the latest variant of the ECS-optimized AMI. It
>   only affects creation of new container instances after opting into
>   awsvpcTrunking. It only affects tasks created with awsvpc network mode
>   and EC2 launch type. Tasks created with the AWS Fargate launch type
>   always have a dedicated network interface, no matter how many you
>   launch.

[optimizing-amazon-ecs-task-density-using-awsvpc-network-mode](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/optimizing-amazon-ecs-task-density-using-awsvpc-network-mode/)

Comment: So then how do you send traffic from one container to another in this case? How would you get the address of the ENI?

Comment: it seems like you are looking for a task network. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html

Comment: What do you mean? That page is just explaining the difference between the different network modes. If you go to the page for awsvpc it says "containers that belong to the same task can communicate over the localhost interface." That isn't the case in my experience. Have you actually gotten it to work that way? Or are you doing something different?

Comment: all container should be part of same task for service to service communication, if they are different task then they cant, you might consider other option like service discovery or internal lb

Comment: That's what this person is saying. They are in the same task.